# Qt OpenCV filestorage

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I am trying to read an .xml file with OpenCV Filestorage, I'm writing my programm with QT. Here is my code:

```
void TProcessing::setCamMat(){
cv::FileStorage fr("calib.xml", cv::FileStorage::READ);
if(!fr.isOpened()){
    std::cout<<"file not found"<<std::endl;
    }
    fr["cameramatrix"] >> this->intr;
    fr["distortion"] >> this->dist;
    std::cout<<dist.size()<<std::endl;
    fr.release();
 }
```

The Problem is that my program can't find the "calib.xml" file.

I wrote the same code in VS and it works without any problem. Any suggestions on what could be the problem?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: oh sorry the problem is that my program don't find the "calib.xml" file.

Comment: Where do you run it? Are you sure the file calib.xml is in the same path as your program?

Comment: Try to use the full path!

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
it works with the full path. but what i want is that it works  with the relative path